# Scroll a fixed position div to its bottom and then stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to build a page just like `Facebook` or `Twitter` where middle div is scrolling infinitive and left or right div is scroll only to its `height` then stops there.

In my website, I am also displaying infinitive data in middle div and some `fixed` height data on right side. I want to `scroll` both div with page `scroll` and right div stops scrolling when it reaches its height and stays there.

What I did is that first make its `position: static` and when it reaches `bottom` of right div make it `fixed`. But it's not what I want because when I change `static` to `fixed`, right div goes to the top again.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div> I am using style disple flex bcoz I dont know how to use bootstap here(On this site)</div>
     <div class="col=lg-12" style="display:flex">
     <div class="col-lg-3" style="position:fixed;float:left;left:0">some text</div>
     <div class="col-lg-6" id="displayPost" style="float:left;left:0;right:0;text-align:center">post display using ajax<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br></div>
     <div id="staticDiv" class="col-lg-3" style="height:100px;float:right;right:0">//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br></div>
    </div>
```

js code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var distanceFromTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (distanceFromTop >= $('#staticDiv').height()) {   
      $('#staticDiv').css({
        position: 'fixed'
      });
    } else { 
      $('#staticDiv').css({
        position: 'absolute'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div> I am using style disple flex bcoz I dont know how to use bootstap here(On this site)</div>
     <div class="col=lg-12" style="display:flex">
     <div class="col-lg-3" style="position:fixed;float:left;left:0">some text</div>
     <div class="col-lg-6" id="displayPost" style="float:left;left:0;right:0;text-align:center">post display using ajax<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br></div>
     <div id="staticDiv" class="col-lg-3" style="height:200px;float:right;right:0">//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br></div>
    </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var distanceFromTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        if (distanceFromTop >= $('#staticDiv').height()) {   
            $('#staticDiv').css({
                position: 'fixed'
            });
        } else { 
            $('#staticDiv').css({
                position: 'absolute'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

All I want is that right side div stay at bottom and fixed while middle div keep scrolling.

Comment: Honestly, I would just use this library : http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/

Comment: @Kiwad thnkx for ur respond, I will loot at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to the code. Check my answer for the differences. I hope it helps.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var distanceFromTop = $(document).scrollTop();
  var h = $('#staticDiv').height()/2;
  if (distanceFromTop >= h) {
    $('#staticDiv').css({
      "position": "fixed",
      "top": "0px",
      "right": "0px"
    });
  } else {
    $('#staticDiv').css({
      "position": 'absolute',
      "top":"0px"
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#staticDiv {
  height:200px;
  right:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> I am using style disple flex bcoz I dont know how to use bootstap here(On this site)</div>
<div class="col=lg-12" style="display:flex; position: relative;">
  <div class="col-lg-3" style="position:fixed;left:0">some text</div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" id="displayPost" style="float:left;left:0;right:0;text-align:center">post display using ajax<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some
    text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some
    text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br></div>
  <div id="staticDiv" class="col-lg-3" style="">//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some
    text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br>//some text<br></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I found my solution. Thnkx for your responce.

Posting my solution here bcoz more suggestions are welcome

```
$(function(){
var lastScroll = 0;
var childLastScroll = 0;
var currentScroll = 0;
var child = document.getElementById('scroll101');
$(window).scroll(function(){
  currentScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  console.log(currentScroll);
  if(lastScroll < currentScroll){
    if(childLastScroll < child.scrollHeight){
      childLastScroll += 20;
    }else{
      childLastScroll = child.scrollHeight;
    }
  }else if(lastScroll > currentScroll){
    if(currentScroll == 0){
      childLastScroll = 0;
    }else{
      if(childLastScroll >= 20){
        childLastScroll -= 20;
      }else{
        childLastScroll = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  $('#scroll101').scrollTop(childLastScroll);
  lastScroll = currentScroll;
});
});
```